# How can I safely overclock CPU ram bus speed?

Tags: memory, cpu, performance, motherboard, overclocking

I have 2*8GB Memory sticks that run at 2400Mhz. My CPU can handle memory speeds up to 1600Mhz according to the specifications. I would rather not tweak voltages since many people say this can harm your PC badly.

My system specs:

- Intel Core i7-4790K Boxed (stock cooler)
- Asus Republic Of Gamers Z97 MAXIMUS VII HERO
- Corsair Vengeance Pro CMY16GX3M2A2400C11R (DDR3-2400 Mhz 2x8GB)
- Seasonic M12II Evo 620W

How can I overclock my CPU or CPU FSB safely to handle higher memory speeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my motherboard I have an option to let the motherboard figure out the optimal settings. Using the F11 button while in the bios it will prompt you with a few questions and show you the possible performance increase after the automated overclock. I think this is probably the safest way to overclock your cpu/ram.

With this automated overclock I got a 10% increase of CPU performance and a 85% increase in memory performance.

Answer (score 0):

Overclocking of your memory needs to be done by the motherboard and is controlled through the BIOS.

If you go beyond what the chip supports then the benefits will be minimal in most cases, but might make a difference in some games.

To do this you need both memory and a motherboard that supports XMP profiles.  As both your memory and MB appears to do this then you need to enable it in the BIOS.

[This post](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2461509/buy-2133mhz-ram-4790k-supports-1600mhz.html) will explain a bit more about the clocking

And [this one](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?49773-Maximus-HERO-VII-XMP) will show how to enable it for your MB.

Comment: So If I were to enable xmp it would overclock my motherboard to transfer 2400Mhz instead of limiting it at 1600Mhz?

Comment: Basically yes. This also explains a bit https://www.howtogeek.com/257766/how-to-enable-intel-xmp-to-make-your-ram-run-at-its-advertised-speeds/